# How to communicate with gdb/mi using stdin using C for Linux and Windows?

Tags: c, linux, windows, subprocess, gdb

i'm try to make a C program to interact with GDB using [GBD MI protocol](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_chapter/gdb_22.html).

First a try to handle the subprocess by myself, but i fund the project [subprocess.h](https://github.com/sheredom/subprocess.h) and start to use it.

In the follow program, I can spawn the new process, read the `stdout` and `stderr`, but when i try to send something to stdin isn't work.

Getting the return from `fprintf`, it is possible to see that 18 bytes are written to the file handle p_stdin, but I do not get any response. Is there any way to check if the stdin handle is correct?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 32
#include "subprocess.h"

int main(void) {
    const char *command_line[] = {"gdb", "--nx", "-quiet","--interpreter=mi3", NULL};
    struct subprocess_s gdb_sp;
    printf("Starting new process\n");
    int gdb_status = subprocess_create(command_line, subprocess_option_search_user_path | subprocess_option_inherit_environment , &gdb_sp);
    if(gdb_status != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erro: can't open GDB, check if its is installed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Started\n");

    FILE *p_stdout = subprocess_stdout(&gdb_sp);
    FILE *p_stderr = subprocess_stderr(&gdb_sp);

    char stdout_buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char stderr_buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
    memset(stdout_buf, 0, sizeof(stdout_buf));
    memset(stderr_buf, 0, sizeof(stderr_buf));

    fgets(stdout_buf, BUFFER_SIZE, p_stdout);
    printf("%s", stdout_buf);
    fgets(stdout_buf, BUFFER_SIZE, p_stdout);
    printf("%s", stdout_buf);

    FILE *p_stdin = subprocess_stdin(&gdb_sp);
    int a = fprintf(p_stdin, "-break-insert main");
    printf("%d\n", a);

    fgets(stdout_buf, BUFFER_SIZE, p_stdout);
    printf("%s", stdout_buf);

    int ret = -1;
    subprocess_join(&gdb_sp, &ret);
    if(ret != 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erro: can't join GDB process!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    assert(!subprocess_destroy(&gdb_sp));

    printf("Press KEY to exit!");
    getchar();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you want to run on your machine, put the code above and the [subprocess.h](https://github.com/sheredom/subprocess.h) in the same folder, you can use the follow CMakeLists.txt to compile.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(gdb-mi)

set (CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

file(GLOB PROJECT_HEADERS *.h)
file(GLOB PROJECT_SOURCES *.c)

source_group("headers" FILES ${PROJECT_HEADERS})
source_group("sources" FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCES})

add_definitions(-DPROJECT_SOURCE_DIR=\"${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}\")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_SOURCES} ${PROJECT_HEADERS})

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME})
```

Tested on:

- Void Linux: gcc 12.2.0
- WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04: gcc 9.4.0
- Windows 11: MSVC 19.38.33134.0

I would like to be able to interact with GDB in a simple way using C, if you have a good example of how to do this communication, for Linux and Windows it would help a lot.

Comment: Have you tried adding a newline at the end of the command: `fprintf(p_stdin, "-break-insert main\n");`?

Comment: Hi, yes i tried with the newline and usign `fgets`, but the result is the same. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Getting the return from fprintf, it is possible to see that 18 bytes are written to the file handle p_stdin, but I do not get any response.

The `subprocess.h` doesn't appear to set any buffering, and documentation for it doesn't even *mention* buffering.

By default, `stdio` on pipes is *fully buffered*, and you need to call `fflush(p_stdin)` to actually send your command to the subprocess.

Comment: OMG I forgot to flush. It worked thank you very much.